VSCode Darkmode PDF-Viewer
Does anyone know of a extensions / PDF viewer in VSCode such that it easily inverts or changes the color of the background (preferably only the background).
I know of the LaTeX Workshop setting but that for me is always quite a hustle to toggle.
I just want a simple toggling between my standard- and darkmode (which is not directly linked with a theme I use)
UPDATE SOLUTION:

Use latex-workshop
extension and add the following code snippets to keybinding.json and
settings.json:
In keybindings.json add:

{
    "key": "shift+cmd+d",
    "command": "settings.cycle.toggleLatexInvert",
    "when": "editorFocus"
}


In settings.json add:

"latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert": 0,
    "settings.cycle": [
      {
        "id": "toggleLatexInvert",
        "values": [
          { "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert": 0 },
          { "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert": 1 }
        ]
      }
    ]

Pressing shift+cmd+d will now toggle the inversion of the pdf


@MarcelausZell If you aren't dead set on vscode, maybe have a look at texstudio. Its build-in pdf viewer has a really good dark mode with inverted colours

Texstudio is not really an option for me. Like K J said a traditional darkmode is not directly possible. I edited my question with a current workaround which inverts the pdf on keybord combination of cmd+shift+d.
(If someone though comes up with a solution of only inverting specific colors e.g. white -> darkgrey and black -> white please post your solution)

This solution works, but neglects to mention that it requires the extension Settings Cycler

you are right I edited the question correspondigly

This from tomoki1207 is a simple PDF viewer for VSCODE and it has a settings to invert colors.
enable invert mode from you settings.json file and add:

"pdf-viewer.invert":true

and for your LaTeX Workshop you can add custom CSS to invert the PDF viewer colors in settings.json like below

"latex-workshop.viewer.pdf.darkmode.invert":true

or if you want to use keyboard shortcut you can use from File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
your available shortcut keys for ex: Ctrl+Shift+P
and custom command in JSON as below:
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleSetting",
  "args": {
    "setting": "pdf-viewer.invert"
  }
}

hope this helps.

This did not quite work for me but I found a similar solution (I think your commands are not up to date). I edit my question with my current solution, thank you though!
